# There is nothing on my Main Frame in Java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am reading the book "Core Java Volume I- Fundamentals 9th Edition- Horstmann, Cay S. & Cornell, Gary_2013" and still learning Java especially Swing and AWT but I have a question about one task that is in the book.
The task is to construct a frame with 3 sectors Northern with username and password. Center a text area and Southern with a button. The main frame is in border layout. And when the user inputs username and password and by clicking the button 'Insert' the username and password is typed in the text area. Here is a picture of the result: 
[image]

So when i try to do this i got a little window like this: 
[image]

Where am I wrong? I can't understand this.
This is the class that extends JFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = screenSize.width;
        int height = screenSize.height;
        setSize(width / 2, height / 2);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        northPanel.add(new JLabel("Username: ", JLabel.RIGHT));
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        northPanel.add(textField);
        northPanel.add(new JLabel("Password: ", JLabel.RIGHT));
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        northPanel.add(passwordField);

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(8, 20);
        JScrollPane centerPanel = new JScrollPane(textArea);


        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton insertButton = new JButton("Insert");
        southPanel.add(insertButton);

        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
    }
}
```

And my MainTestMethod is like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainTestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        mainFrame.setTitle("Krisko Beatz");
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setLocation(500, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();` to `JFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();`

Comment: Voting to close as a trivial typographical error.

Answer (score 3):

Change `JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();` to `JFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();`

You can remove...

```
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = screenSize.width;
    int height = screenSize.height;
    setSize(width / 2, height / 2);
```

and instead, place a call to `pack();` at the end of the constructor, it will generate a more reliable size of the UI

Comment: Then pls accept as answer